# How can I see the status of the Ethereum network?

Tags: ethereum

Where can I find information such as the latest block, hash difficulty, average block times, difficulty over time, mining pool sizes, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

"status" can mean a few different things:

**Real-time data:** http://stats.ethdev.com

**"historical" data (i.e. "x over time"):**  https://etherchain.org/statistics/basic

**"historical" data alternative:** http://etherscan.io/charts

**Market cap:** http://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/

**Price:** https://poloniex.com/exchange#btc_eth

And, of course, you can get some data straight from the horse's mouth with any of the ethereum clients. Geth, for instance, will spit out information like so:

```
I1119 05:42:27.850525    3419 blockchain.go:1142] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 2 txs in 10.879276ms. #564372 [cc3c199d / cc3c199d]
I1119 05:42:35.415481    3419 blockchain.go:1142] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 2 txs in 8.48831ms. #564373 [fc24f250 / fc24f250]
```

This information includes the latest blocks, timestamps, # of txs and # of uncles.